# How to extract the output of called program RAZUGA01

Tags: abap, sap-erp

My custom report has to call the standard report `RAZUGA01` and extract its output (to get the amounts).

The following instruction does not extract the output:

```
  SUBMIT razuga01
    WITH SELECTION-TABLE it_selection
    EXPORTING LIST TO MEMORY
    AND RETURN.
```

Comment: did you call function module LIST_FROM_MEMORY to get the output? Can you show us your code (more than just that one line)?

Comment: Thank's @Dirik. Next I have CALL FUNCTION 'LIST_FROM_MEMORY but I have Exceptions 1.

Comment: then please extend your code example and add the exception details (message id, message number, error text if available)

Comment: Excpetions is file not found. The standard report returns data with write, the submit statement is correct to access the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me this code works:

```
DATA: lt_seltab  TYPE TABLE OF rsparams,
      ls_seltab  LIKE LINE OF lt_seltab,
      t_list     TYPE TABLE OF abaplist.

DATA: xlist TYPE TABLE OF abaplist.
DATA: xtext TYPE TABLE OF char200.

ls_seltab-kind    = 'S'.
ls_seltab-sign    = 'I'.
ls_seltab-option  = 'EQ'.

ls_seltab-selname = 'BERDATUM'.          " Name of parameter on submitted program
ls_seltab-low     = '20061231'.
APPEND ls_seltab TO lt_seltab.

ls_seltab-selname = 'BUKRS'.
ls_seltab-low     = '0005'.
APPEND ls_seltab TO lt_seltab.

SUBMIT razuga01 WITH SELECTION-TABLE lt_seltab EXPORTING LIST TO MEMORY AND RETURN.

CALL FUNCTION 'LIST_FROM_MEMORY'
  TABLES
    listobject = xlist.

CALL FUNCTION 'LIST_TO_TXT'
  EXPORTING
    list_index         = -1
  TABLES
    listtxt            = xtext
    listobject         = xlist.
```

[image]

If it doesn't work for you, probably you have some erroneous parameters in seltab.

Of course you will have to do some additional parsing to transform these result into human-readable form.

Answer (score 1):

```
cl_salv_bs_runtime_info=>set( exporting display  = abap_false metadata = abap_false   data = abap_true ).
submit razuga01
    with #Here you parameters from selection screen
    and return.
try.
  "Get data from SALV model
  cl_salv_bs_runtime_info=>get_data_ref( importing r_data = lo_data ).
  assign lo_data->* to <outtab>.
  catch cx_salv_bs_sc_runtime_info.
endtry.
cl_salv_bs_runtime_info=>clear_all( ).
```

Try this code you will be able to get ALV table from standard report

Comment: Thank's @fixeln. The report razuga01 don't have a salv table. Can your solution be applied anyway?

Comment: I tried your solution but I always get a sy-subrc eq 4. How could I solve? Thank's

Comment: No, if razuga01 doesn't return any ALV table you can't use my solution.

Comment: Razuga01 return one table create with write istruction. You can help me